# Is this a good way to politely refuse to publish an "abstract" option via e-mail? / 丁寧にメールで要旨原稿を掲載することを断る

Tags: expressions, keigo

## 日本語

## 背景

数ヶ月前、私は地方の学会で学術発表をしました。先日審査の結果を知らされました。結局、通常通りに掲載されることにはならず、要旨としての掲載となるとのことでした。私が掲載を希望するかどうかを尋ねられましたが、私自身は他の研究に集中したいため、要旨原稿の掲載を断るつもりです。

## 質問

以下の日本語はメールの要旨を書くチャンスを断る表現として、相応しいですか：

> ○○先生
>
> 先日のメールを拝見させていただました。
>
> わたくしの都合により、要旨原稿を書かないことになります。
>
> わたくしの発表と原稿をご覧なさってくれて、誠にありがとうございます。

特に、「わたくしの都合...」の文章が丁寧または失礼な印象を与えるかどうかを聞きたいです。

もちろん、どんな表現がよいかは上下関係によるのですが、私は大学講師、相手は名誉教授でいらっしゃいます。

## 英語

## Background

A few months ago, I presented at a small academic conference in my area. The other day I heard the result of my presentation. Ultimately, they won't publish it as a normal article but they are willing to publish it as an "abstract." They are asking me whether I want this or not. I would like to focus on other research and refuse the opportunity to have it published as an abstract.

## My Question

Is the following text appropriate or rude given the circumstances?

> ○○先生
>
> 先日のメールを拝見させていただました。
>
> わたくしの都合により、要旨原稿を書かないことになります。
>
> わたくしの発表と原稿をご覧なさってくれて、誠にありがとうございます。

What I am trying to say is:

> X-Sensei
>
> [Polite expression to indicate I received and read his e-mail ]
>
> Based on my own circumstances, I won't be able to write the abstract.
>
> Thank you for your time in listening to and reading my presentation.

Particularly, what I would like to ask is whether the わたくしの都合 sentence is polite or rude as a way of refusing.

Of course, what expression is appropriate depends on the [vertical] nature of the relationship. I'm a university lecturer, and he's a professor emeritus.

Comment: It's confusing. Which 3rd sentence do you mean? :)

Comment: The third sentence in the quote, "わたくしの都合により、要旨原稿を書かないことになります。" (Is that confusing?)

Comment: あ、そうか・・・「○○先生」を「１文」と数えるかどうか、で・・・

Comment: なるほど、最初に日本語に書いていたから「○○先生」は文章と数えたのですが、英語に考えると非常に変ですね。（日本語の場合が分からない）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about...

> ○○先生、
>   先日はメールをいただきまして、ありがとうございました。
>   誠に勝手とは存じますが、今回の論文要旨の掲載はご辞退させていただきたいと思います。
>   私の発表と原稿をご覧いただきまして、ありがとうございました。

Comment: そのあとに「また機会がございましたらよろしくお願いいたします。」とか「今後もご指導ご鞭撻、お願い申し上げます。」とか足したらいいかと・・・